# Dereferencing pointer to incomplete type in C (pointer to struct)

Tags: c, pointers, struct, typedef

I'm having this error "Dereferencing pointer to incomplete type" in my main.c, line 14, when I try to use the pointer to the struct for the first time (in main). These are my files:

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "struttura_dati.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
Prodotti *prodotti;
int i, k, nc=0;

k=atoi(argv[1]);

prodotti=leggi_medicinali();

printf("%d", prodotti->categorie[0]);

free(prodotti); /*da liberare anche vett */
return 0;
}
```

struttura_dati.h

```
#ifndef STRUTTURA_DATI_
#define STRUTTURA_DATI_

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXNOME 21          /* max lunghezza nomi */
#define MAXPROD 50          /* max numero prodotti */
#define MAXDITT 10          /* max numero ditte */

typedef struct strutt_dati medicinale;
typedef struct vett_struct Prodotti;

Prodotti* leggi_medicinali();
int cerca(char temp[MAXNOME], char database[MAXPROD][MAXNOME], int n);
void stampa(char stringa[]);

#endif
```

struttura_dati.c

```
#include "struttura_dati.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct strutt_dati {
char nome[MAXNOME];
int ditta;
int categoria;
};

struct vett_struct {
medicinale *vett;
char ditte[MAXDITT][MAXNOME];
char categorie[MAXPROD][MAXNOME];
int n_categorie;
int n_ditte;
};

Prodotti* leggi_medicinali() {

int i=0, fl;
char temp_categ[MAXNOME], temp_ditta[MAXNOME];
FILE *fp;

Prodotti* leggi_medicinali() {

int i=0, fl;
char temp_categ[MAXNOME], temp_ditta[MAXNOME];
FILE *fp;

Prodotti* prodotti;

fp=fopen("Medicinali.txt", "r");
if(fp==NULL) {
    printf("Errore nell'apertura del file ''Medicinali.txt''\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

prodotti=malloc(MAXPROD*sizeof(Prodotti*));
prodotti->vett=malloc(MAXPROD*sizeof(medicinale));

prodotti->n_categorie=0;
prodotti->n_ditte=0;


while(!feof(fp)) {
    fscanf(fp, "%s %s %s", temp_categ, prodotti->vett[i].nome, temp_ditta);
    fl=cerca(temp_categ, prodotti->categorie, prodotti->n_categorie);
    if(fl==-1) {
        strcpy(prodotti->categorie[prodotti->n_categorie], temp_categ);
        prodotti->vett[i].categoria=prodotti->n_categorie;
        prodotti->n_categorie++;
    }
    else
        prodotti->vett[i].categoria=fl;

    fl=cerca(temp_ditta, prodotti->ditte, prodotti->n_ditte);
    if(fl==-1) {
        strcpy(prodotti->ditte[prodotti->n_ditte], temp_ditta);
        prodotti->vett[i].ditta=prodotti->n_ditte;
        prodotti->n_ditte++;
    }
    else
        prodotti->vett[i].ditta=fl;
    i++;
}
printf("%s ", prodotti->categorie[0]); /* THIS, IN struttura_dati.c WORKS, BUT IT DOESN'T IN main.c */
fclose(fp);
return prodotti;
}
```

Could you please help me understand why the main.c can't use properly everything with prodotti->(something)? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These definitions:

```
struct strutt_dati {
char nome[MAXNOME];
int ditta;
int categoria;
};

struct vett_struct {
medicinale *vett;
char ditte[MAXDITT][MAXNOME];
char categorie[MAXPROD][MAXNOME];
int n_categorie;
int n_ditte;
};
```

need to be in `struttura_dati.h`, not `struttura_dati.c`.  Currently, when you use the structs in `main.c` the definitions are not visible.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I did that because I need to make an ADT (I'll make it better later, now I'm just sketching the code..). However, I used this method to define structs other times and it worked, why it's not working now? it's the only way that I know to have, later, an ADT..

Comment: If you really want to hide the struct definition, you could make functions implemented in `struttura_dati.c` that operate on pointers to the struct.

Answer (score 0):

The way the code is currently structured, I think you'll have a NULL referencing problem even if you solve your current issue. In your main.c you have declared,

```
Prodotti *prodotti;
```

which you (presumably) fill with;

```
prodotti=leggi_medicinali();
```

But have a look at the function as its currently quoted;

```
Prodotti* leggi_medicinali() {

    int i=0, fl;
    char temp_categ[MAXNOME], temp_ditta[MAXNOME];
    FILE *fp;

    Prodotti* prodotti;

    (... things that works)

    return;
}
```

See that final "return" ? What does it really do? Does it return anything? It just shifts control back to the main function which is left wanting for a return value. I'm actually surprised that the compiler didn't pick this up.

Comment: Ops, I'm really sorry, I forgot to write it in the question, however in the code I have "return prodotti" but, however, it doesn't work. :/

Comment: I've added Prodotti* prodotti to the first post, now there is everything but it's a quite long code, answer me only if you want to.